# Issue With "emoji" Not being defined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been working on a very basic reaction edit system. (very basic) just so you can flip through 3 embeds and that's it. There's a error that is says it doesn't  know the meaning of "emoji". I found a different one on it but it was different part.

**Error:**

(node:66884) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined
at C:\Users\eric\OneDrive\Desktop\TDK Bot\commands\pstats.js:126:54
(node:66884) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 22)

And here's the code:

```
            message.channel.send(first).then(firstReact => {
            firstReact.react('➡️');

            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['➡️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
            };
        
            firstReact.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000})
                .then(collected => {
                    const reaction = collected.first();
        
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '➡️'){
                        firstReact.edit(second);
                        firstReact.reactions.removeAll().then(secondReact => {
                            secondReact.react('➡️');

                            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                                return ['➡️',].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
                            };

                            secondReact.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000})
                                .then(collected => {
                                    const reaction = collected.first();
                                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '➡️'){
                                        secondReact.edit(third);
                                    }
                                    })
                                })
                    }
                        
                    
                    
                });
        })
```

Comment: This means that `reaction` is undefined. Do you know which line it specifically indicates?

Comment: At Both "if (reaction.emoji.name == '➡️')

Comment: What's `firstReact`?

Comment: Function parameter

Comment: It seems like from [this example](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#awaiting-reactions) you don't need it at all. You could just use `message` instead of `firstReact`.